# VS Code - How do you actually use an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

in Visual studio code how do you use and extension?

So I've installed 'Insert Line Number' by Anders Liu.

But how do I actual use it? On their demo video they magically open this dialog box and search for their extension then click on it.

what do I do?

Comment: 'The magical dialog box' sounds like Ctrl+Shift+P.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thats what I thought, but in their magic demo video whatever 'magic box' they pull up, they start to type 'insert line ..... ' and then 'insert line number' gets found and they click on that. But when I do cmd+shit+p start to stop that in it finds nothing even remotely close to that. I have the extension installed and enabled

Comment: try `View > Command Palette`. Maybe you have a different keyboard shortcut